# How do I run a two-part model of health care expenditures in Stata?

Tags: logistic, stata

Does anyone have Stata code they could share with me so that I can run a two-part model to look at health care expenditures? The first part of the model will determine whether or not an individual had any visit and the second part will determine how much individuals spent (estimated on the subset of those who had a visit). I know that I need to take the product of these to get the expected cost of health care for individual i and also need to do a transformation for the first part but I am not sure how to do this in Stata. Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to post or link to some example data to get any help.  It would also help if you posted some code you wrote that attempts to solve this problem, to give the rest of us something to work with.

Comment: It seems that you wanna do some heckman correction for selecetion bias. I don't know stata very well, but I know there is a function for that. look for heckman correction at stata help. It might help.

Answer (score 1):

See the code from "Modeling Health Care Costs and Use" presentations by Deb, Manning, and Norton. Aviable via Google or http://urban.hunter.cuny.edu/~deb/